# ScanLine flood fill Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10b48427c)

Tags: objective-c, flood-fill, scanline

[image]I used https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill to implement Scanline flood fill in my swift code. Sometimes the image is filled sometimes it throws an exception like

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10b48427c)
```

in getColorCode function of the UIImage+FloodFill.m file which is obj-c I used bridging header to implement the code please help...

Comment: Check the `byteIndex` value using a breakpoint. As I can see in the screenshot, it seems much upper than your array's bounds.

Comment: byte index values are intact but if I run the app in simulator 11.2 v it runs smoothly but in physical device 11.3 v the error shows is this bcoz of the version @HassanShahbazi

Comment: Edit your question and share your code where you are using this function. So, I can help you more.